# If Arg$(z)=3\pi/4$ and Arg$(w)=\pi/2$, then why is Arg$(zw)=-3\pi/4$ instead of the sum, $5\pi/4$?

Tags: complex-numbers

A question from my textbook asks, given $\operatorname{Arg}(z) = 3\pi/4$ and $\operatorname{Arg}(w) = \pi/2$, to find $\operatorname{Arg}(zw)$. So, I add $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ and $\operatorname{Arg}(w)$ and get $5\pi/4$.

But when I check the solution they mention it in the following form: 
$5\pi/4 - 2\pi = -3\pi/4$.

Why is it mentioned in this form?

Comment: It is due to the definition of Arg. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value

Comment: Maybe because $-3\pi/4$ is between $\pi$ and $-\pi$, unlike $5\pi/4$.

Comment: I hope that you can forgive me for editing the title of your question, but it was misleading as it stood.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley To the contrary! I'm new here, so I highly appreciate any guidance to fit better in the community.

Comment: I'll never forgive that dirty rotten swine Blue for re-editing my edit! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\theta$ is an argument for $z$, then so are the numbers $\theta + 2\pi k$ for all integers $k$ (since $re^{i\theta}=re^{i\theta +2ki\pi}$).

But $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$, with capital "A", is usually defined to be the specific argument that lies in $(-\pi,\pi]$. That is, you always must have $-\pi< \operatorname{Arg}(z)\leq \pi$. (There are other definitions of the "principle" range, but this is pretty common.)

So you need to add or subtract integral multiples of $2\pi$ to your answer until the result is in the required range.